# HTML текст при генерации excel файла с помощью PHPExcel

Tags: php, xls

Я создаю view:

```
$offerView = View::make('createOffer')->with(['content' => $content])->render();
```

потом пытаюсь поместить это view в ячейку:

```
->SetCellValue('D'.$ii, $offerView)
```

И на выходе получаю в этой ячейке html-теги.

Как сделать, чтобы не было html-тегов?

Comment: strip_tags() не подходит. Как вариант заменить <br/> на {код переноса строки} в exel. но вот какую аббревиатуру вставить

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит попробовать вот так:

```
->SetCellValue('D'.$ii, strip_tags($offerView))
```

Comment: нет так не подходит ,  в html  есть теги <br/> . Они должны отработать  и форматированный текст должен добавиться  в exel

Comment: function br2nl ( $string )
{
    return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', PHP_EOL, $string);
}

->SetCellValue('D'.$ii, strip_tags(br2nl($offerView)));

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо

function br2nl ( $string ) { return preg_replace('/\/i', PHP_EOL, $string); } ->SetCellValue('D'.$ii, strip_tags(br2nl($offerView)));

Помогло